# cordova/phonegap documentation confusion

Tags: cordova

I find the cordova/phonegap documentation very confusing, especially with relation to ios.

for example: in http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/config_ref_index.md.html
it say:

> ```
> Orientation allows you to lock orientation and prevent the interface from rotating in response to changes in orientation.
> ```
>
> Possible values are default, landscape, or portrait. Example:
>
> ```
> <preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
> ```

which is not working at all.

Also, none of the plugin I found pass compilation (mostly missing files issues).

I have a feeling it is an issue of versioning, but none of the docs I read mentioned any thing about it.

so my questions:

1. how to lock orientation?
2. how do I find the correct documentation?
   e.g. the link I supply has the '3.3.0' which I guess means the version, but I couldn't find documentation for the config xml in v2.

Comment: There is no `config.xml` in Cordova 2.x, why don't you update to 3.x? It is much easier to use because of the cli tools.

Comment: 3.x dosent work on ripple, for me phonegap is useless if I cannot debug in broswer, how do I debug 3.x?

Comment: If you install the newest version of Ripple from npm it supports Cordova 3.x.

Look here (http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/11/5/Ripple-is-Reborn) for instructions to install it via npm.

Comment: I tried the new Ripple, it didn't work, but I found that u can develop in the browser with v2.9 and deploy to the device with 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

In 3.3 - ios - locking the orientation is done in *-info.plist by setting:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

Note: you should delete the unnecessary values from the default generated plist.